# How to make Crystal Reports Page Width Larger During Design of .rpt

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm looking for a method to resize the page width Crystal Reports gives me to place fields in my .rpt file.

So far I have discovered if I right click on the report, select 'design'/'printer setup', I can select the size of the paper I want the report to print out on.  If I select 'Orientation/Landscape' I can increase the width of the page and I can place more fields on the report.

My goal: Place all of my fields on my report (around 25 of them) and export the data to Excel.  Right now I do not have enough width to place all of the fields in the .rpt file.

Is there a way to increase the width of the page to an arbitrary number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=754

Basically add a dummy printer to your system that can take a larger paper size and select that as your printer for the report.

Comment: +1 for the solution, but this is such a crazy workaround. Why couldn't they make an input box so you can add a custom page size?

Answer (score 7):

1. By changing your reports paper size. Make it to legal/letter etc will increase width of your reports so that you can easily display number of columns (more than 10) on your report.

   To do that Right click --> Design --> Printer Setup -->Paper --> Size .
2. Another way can be by changing your reports orientation. By default it is Portrait. You can change it to Landscape by

   Right click --> Design --> Printer Setup --> Orientation -->Landscape (Radio button.)
3. File --> Printer Setup --> properties 
   orientation 
   select Portrait

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to   Printers and Faxes
2. Select Printer
3. Go To   File / Server Properties
4. Go To   Click New Form
5. Go To   New Form -- > Write a Name of PaperSize
6. Go To   New Form -- > Write a Name of PaperSize
7. Go To   measurements Unit -- > Set Paper Size  Wdith and Hight , Margin
8. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
9. Goto Crystal Report - > Page Setup
10. Page options - > Selecte your new created papper Size

Answer (score 1):

use the microsoft xps document writer as your dummy printer, and create a new form from server properties as the post above me states.

Comment: “post above me” doesn't really work here, since the answers are shuffled around – better point to someone's name/alias.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I should add the actual steps here from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/429057/107537), rather than go link hunting to do it (it points to another link). What worked for me in crystal reports was:

1. File > Printer Setup
2. Choose printer "Microsoft Office Document Image writer"
3. Paper > Custom Size
4. <kbd>Properties</kbd> (next to printer name)
5. Enter custom size, and <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd> and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

I set the printer to something absurdly wide and use that.  ben's link is the right idea.

Answer (score -1):

I realize that this is a very old topic and the question is about design mode but since this question keeps coming up in my Google searches, I expect that this may help someone.  So, I just wanted to add that programmatically, this can be done without a dummy printer like this:

```
var repDoc = new ReportDocument();
repDoc.Load(rpt_path);

ISCDReportClientDocument clientDoc = repDoc.ReportClientDocument;
clientDoc.PrintOutputController.ModifyUserPaperSize(repDoc.PrintOptions.PageContentHeight, repDoc.PrintOptions.PageContentWidth * 2);
```