# How to export a crystal report as a fixed character into a text file

Tags: crystal-reports, export, text-files

I'm trying to export a formula with fixed characters spacing into a text file. 
What is happening is that its a long set of fields that is longer then the report page in crystal can show. When running the report it places the additional fields under  and it repeats for all the records. When I try to export it to a text file it is pushing it the same way instead of that one record being one whole line across on the text file like I would like it to be. How can this be done. New to crystal thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this report solely being used for exporting to a plaintext file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're exporting to plaintext, I'm assuming you don't care what the format of the actual report is (since it is merely an intermediate player during the export process). If that's the case, then you can just expand the page size horizontally until it can accommodate all of your fields the way you want them.

Your page size is probably 8.5"x11" by default. Go into your Page Setup ("File" -> "Page Setup") and make it the size that suits your fields.

[image: Page Setup screen for custom page size 30" wide]

EDIT: If you're using an older version of CR, you may have to use a dummy printer that can accommodate large paper sizes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429035/how-to-make-crystal-reports-page-width-larger-during-design-of-rpt).

Comment: I dont have that option in page setup. I'm using Crystal 11.5.12

Comment: @Dagz200 You don't have which option?

Comment: See my edit. Also, as long as you're able to edit the "Horizontal" setting under "Page Options" then none of the other settings should matter.

Comment: What version do you have in CR, it does not look the same on my version.

Comment: @Dagz200 That screenshot is from CR2008. If you cannot manually enter in height/width then you'll need to create a dummy printer with custom paper sizes.

Comment: Yea that's pretty much what I did, it worked thanks for your help.