# Adjusting Crystal Reports fields based on paper size

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, crystal-reports

[image]I have a Crystal report which has invoice details. Iam adding data from sale datagridview to crystal reports using dataset. Currently i am setting it to A4 size. Now i am making a new form to customize crystal reports size, text etc. My problem is if i select any small size instead of A4 the size of paper shrinks and the data fields are going out of the border. How can i adjust data fields automatically upon paper size change? and ine more question.. is it possible to change crystal reports header and papersize from user input from a new form. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: it may use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429035/how-to-make-crystal-reports-page-width-larger-during-design-of-rpt

Comment: Any other answers

Answer (score 1):

Crystal report has a limit width only you can expand your width by:

In VISUAL STUDIO:
Goto > Crystal Reports > Design > Page Setup...>

[image]

Comment: You can use margins also if you want.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my problem. Please check the updated question.

Comment: You can adjust the font or make it a landscape. You don't have any choice. Or Compress your fields.

Comment: If i select size A5, it will look like the what i have showed as screenshot. then i have to drag all the fields gone outside to inside. I want it to automatically constraint upon size.

Comment: @Abhijith Use A5Rotated paper size